# Implementing a fast DBScan in C#

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, tree, clustering

I tried to implement a DBScan in C# using kd-trees. I followed the implementation from [here](http://www.yzuzun.com/2015/07/dbscan-clustering-algorithm-and-c-implementation/).

```
public class DbscanAlgorithm
{
    private readonly Func<PointD, PointD, double> _metricFunc;


    public DbscanAlgorithm(Func<PointD, PointD, double> metricFunc)
    {
        _metricFunc = metricFunc;
    }

    public void ComputeClusterDbscan(ScanPoint[] allPoints, double epsilon, int minPts, out HashSet<ScanPoint[]> clusters)
    {
        clusters = null;
        var allPointsDbscan = allPoints.Select(x => new DbscanPoint(x)).ToArray();

        var tree = new KDTree.KDTree<DbscanPoint>(2);
        for (var i = 0; i < allPointsDbscan.Length; ++i)
        {
            tree.AddPoint(new double[] { allPointsDbscan[i].ClusterPoint.point.X, allPointsDbscan[i].ClusterPoint.point.Y }, allPointsDbscan[i]);
        }

        var C = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < allPointsDbscan.Length; i++)
        {
            var p = allPointsDbscan[i];
            if (p.IsVisited)
                continue;
            p.IsVisited = true;

            DbscanPoint[] neighborPts = null;
            RegionQuery(tree, p.ClusterPoint.point, epsilon, out neighborPts);
            if (neighborPts.Length < minPts)
                p.ClusterId = (int)ClusterIds.NOISE;
            else
            {
                C++;
                ExpandCluster(tree, p, neighborPts, C, epsilon, minPts);
            }
        }
        clusters = new HashSet<ScanPoint[]>(
            allPointsDbscan
                .Where(x => x.ClusterId > 0)
                .GroupBy(x => x.ClusterId)
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.ClusterPoint).ToArray())
            );

        return;
    }

    private void ExpandCluster(KDTree.KDTree<DbscanPoint> tree, DbscanPoint p, DbscanPoint[] neighborPts, int c, double epsilon, int minPts)
    {
        p.ClusterId = c;
        for (int i = 0; i < neighborPts.Length; i++)
        {
            var pn = neighborPts[i];
            if (!pn.IsVisited)
            {
                pn.IsVisited = true;
                DbscanPoint[] neighborPts2 = null;
                RegionQuery(tree, pn.ClusterPoint.point, epsilon, out neighborPts2);
                if (neighborPts2.Length >= minPts)
                {
                    neighborPts = neighborPts.Union(neighborPts2).ToArray();
                }
            }
            if (pn.ClusterId == (int)ClusterIds.UNCLASSIFIED)
                pn.ClusterId = c;
        }
    }

    private void RegionQuery(KDTree.KDTree<DbscanPoint> tree, PointD p, double epsilon, out DbscanPoint[] neighborPts)
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        var pIter = tree.NearestNeighbors(new double[] { p.X, p.Y }, 10, epsilon);
        while (pIter.MoveNext())
        {
            totalCount++;
        }
        neighborPts = new DbscanPoint[totalCount];
        int currCount = 0;
        pIter.Reset();
        while (pIter.MoveNext())
        {
            neighborPts[currCount] = pIter.Current;
            currCount++;
        }

        return;
    }
}

//Dbscan clustering identifiers
public enum ClusterIds
{
    UNCLASSIFIED = 0,
    NOISE = -1
}

//Point container for Dbscan clustering
public class DbscanPoint
{
    public bool IsVisited;
    public ScanPoint ClusterPoint;
    public int ClusterId;

    public DbscanPoint(ScanPoint point)
    {
        ClusterPoint = point;
        IsVisited = false;
        ClusterId = (int)ClusterIds.UNCLASSIFIED;
    }
}
```

and modifying the `regionQuery(P, eps)` to invoke the nearest neighbour function of a kd-tree. To do so, I used the `kd-sharp` library for C#, which is one of the fastest kd-tree implementations out there.

However, when given a dataset of about 20000 2d points, its performance is in the region of 40s, as compared to the `scikit-learn` Python implementation of DBScan, which given the same parameters, takes about 2s.

Since this algorithm is for a C# program that I am writing, I am stuck using C#. As such, I would like to find out what am I still missing out in terms of optimization of the algorithm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_metricFunc` is unused, which means it can either be removed, or there's a bug in the program.

The first line in `ComputeClusterDbscan`, `clusters = null;`, is superfluous and can be removed.

The use of `out` parameters can be avoided by just returning a value.

Methods that can be marked `static` should be marked `static`.

In `RegionQuery`, it is probably faster to iterate over nearest neighbours just one, like so:

```
private static DbscanPoint[] RegionQuery(KDTree<DbscanPoint> tree, PointD p, double epsilon)
{
    var neighbors = new List<DbscanPoint>();
    var e = tree.NearestNeighbors(new[] { p.X, p.Y }, 10, epsilon);
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        neighbors.Add(e.Current);
    }

    return neighbors.ToArray();
}
```

I believe the bottleneck in your program is this line in `ExpandCluster`:

> ```
> neighborPts = neighborPts.Union(neighborPts2).ToArray();
> ```

Try something like this instead:

```
private static void ExpandCluster(KDTree<DbscanPoint> tree, DbscanPoint p, DbscanPoint[] neighborPts, int c, double epsilon, int minPts)
{
    p.ClusterId = c;

    var queue = new Queue<DbscanPoint>(neighborPts);
    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var point = queue.Dequeue();
        if (point.ClusterId == (int)ClusterIds.UNCLASSIFIED)
        {
            point.ClusterId = c;
        }

        if (point.IsVisited)
        {
            continue;
        }

        point.IsVisited = true;
        var neighbors = RegionQuery(tree, point.ClusterPoint.point, epsilon);
        if (neighbors.Length >= minPts)
        {
            foreach (var neighbor in neighbors.Where(neighbor => !neighbor.IsVisited))
            {
                queue.Enqueue(neighbor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in `RegionQuery` if `NearestNeighbors` returns an `IEnumerable` (unfortunately we don't know it) (I guess an enumerator) it would be faster to just call `ToArray` instead of creating a `List<>` first and then `ToArray` it (iterating it twice) or still better make the `ReqionQuery` return an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @t3chb0t Thanks for the comment. You can find the source of `NearestNeighbors<T>` [here](https://code.google.com/p/kd-sharp/source/browse/trunk/KDTree/NearestNeighbour.cs) -- it only implements `IEnumerator`. I wouldn't want to return an `IEnumerable<DbscanPoint>` since the calling methods need to know the number of elements. But now you've got me thinking changing `RegionQuery` to return an `ICollection<DbscanPoint>` (or `IReadOnlyCollection<DbscanPoint>`) is a good choice.